# Why don't my two sample ever have 0 numbers in common?

Tags: python, random

I've written a program that samples two lists between 0-9. I then see how many numbers they have in common, and it to a corresponding counter. I've looped this 1000000, but the samples never have 0 numbers in common. Is there something wrong with my code, or am i just extremely unlucky

```py
for _ in range(1000000):

    House_deal = random.sample(range(9), k=5)
    Player_deal = random.sample(range(9), k=5)

    hc = Counter(House_deal)
    pc = Counter(Player_deal)
    common = hc.keys() & pc.keys() #get the intersection of both keys
    counts = 0

    for cel in common:
        counts += min(hc[cel], pc[cel])
    if counts == 0:
        common_0 += 1
    elif counts == 1:
        common_1 += 1
    elif counts == 2:
        common_2 += 1
    elif counts == 3:
        common_3 += 1
    elif counts == 4:
        common_4 += 1
    elif counts == 5:
        common_5 += 1
```

Comment: shouldn't you add the numbers in **common[0]** instead of **common_0** ?

Comment: `random.sample(range(9),5)` takes 5 different values from a list of 9 different values. If you do that twice there will always be at least 1 value in common (5 + 5 = 10 which is > 9).

Comment: You're taking 5 elements out of 9 with no duplicates.  You then do it a second time.  So at least one of the elements from the first set of 5 *must* be in the second set of 5, since only 4 of the 9 values are not, and you are taking 5.  Try to construct a counter-example.  You won't be able to.

Comment: Doesn't range(9) include zero? I.E shouldn't there be a result like H.C[0,1,2,3,4,] P.C[5,6,7,8,9]?

Comment: @AidenRichards Yes, `range(9)` includes 0.  However, it does not include 9.

Answer (score 0):

What I believe you're looking to do is determine the most common among a trial of `hc` v.s. `pc` 1000000 times. Something like this should do. Your main issue is you're not tracking these numbers outside the loop. I'm unsure what `count` was for though?

```
from random import sample
from collections import Counter

common = Counter()

for _ in range(1000000):
  House_deal = sample(range(9), k=5)
  Player_deal = sample(range(9), k=5)

  common.update(set(House_deal).intersection(Player_deal))
```